# Solar powered automatic bell system with smoke detection using raspberry pi

Tags: embedded, project, raspberry-pi4

Guys I want to ask if possible to create a solar powered automatic bell system with smoke detection using raspberry pi? And I worries if the raspberry pi have real time clock? Because I need a RTC to execute the bell in exact alarm for certain interval I set.

This the statement I find in internet for more details but the author used an arduino.

The system uses the real time clock to determine

the time and the bell rings based on set up time. The LCD

in this system displays current time and displays fire if

the smoke detector detects a smoke. For different

sessions, the bell will ring different numbers of times.

The system is expected to continuously display the time

by using real time clock and monitor the situation of the

school during the day and night with power generated by

solar energy [9]. By using solar energy as a power source,

the system is uninterrupted during power supply failure

from the main energy department. In addition, the energy

can be used efficiently during day time and stored energy

in the battery can be utilized during night time. This

designed bell system integrated with smoke detector

integration is expected to safeguard the institution from

damages and losses particularly during an outbreak of

fire.

Comment: I very strongly recommend you do not use any DIY project for anything safety related.  Also solar power is not a smart move for something that requires high reliability.  These type of systems typically are either entirely battery powered or mains powered with a backup battery.

Answer (score 0):

Your project is indeed feasible. The RPI check for the smoke detector value at a certain interval of time. If the value is higher than a certain threshold then you ring your bell.

The raspberry pi does not have a RTC included. You'll have to buy one online (a simple research on google should lead you to online shop like adafruit ...). But I don't understand why you would need to use a real time clock. If you want to use this system (which I don't recommend ; use a certified equipment for your personal security) you should check the data from the smoke/fire detector quite regularly but it doesn't have to be matching real time clock.

Alternatively, you could use RPI WiFi/Ethernet to request RTC from the internet.

If you are doing this project just for fun, use a smoke detector and a buzzer. Your RPI should be able to provide enough current to power both of these equipment. You could power your RPI with a small battery or a charger (check the correct voltage & current needed by the RPI).

You should find a lot of information/tutorials/code online for these type of little projects.